# Direct stdout of Python popen to multiple places

Tags: python, shell, unix, command-line, process

I currently have:

```
    mpstat = Popen(["mpstat", "1", mpstat_duration], stdout = PIPE)
    grep = Popen(["grep", "Average"], stdin = mpstat.stdout, stdout = PIPE)
    mpstat.stdout.close()
    result, err_msg = grep.communicate()
    result = result.strip().split()
```

Which runs mpstat, greps the average, and stores the line I want in a variable.

Is there a way to, in addition to that, also write the stdout to a file at the same time? I want to have Both the current 'result' variable, and a file containing the stdout of mpstat.

Comment: Why not `with open('myfile', 'w') as file: file.write(result)` before the `result = result.strip...` line?

Comment: The thing is, 'result' is not the full mpstat result. 'result' is already the grepped version of mpstat's stdout. @zondo

Comment: You should be able to say `mstat.stdout.seek(0); with open('myfile', 'w') as file: file.write(mstat.read())`